# VBA-Excel How to find an email address from an exchange user in Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have been trying to import a contact's email based on an input name.  I am not that good at macro programming but have found a code that works.  However it only works by looking up the information in the contacts folder and I need it to lookup a contact in the Global Address List give me back the email associated with that person. I have searched through other posts and they all want to take every contact from outlook and paste it to excel.  I only want to search the Global Address List for a person based on the input name and have it return the email of that person.

Here is what I have:

```
Function GrabContactInfo(rRng As Range, iWanted As Integer) As String

Dim olA As Outlook.Application

Dim olNS As Namespace

Dim olAB As MAPIFolder

Dim lItem As Long   

Dim sNameWanted As String

Dim sRetValue As String

Set olA = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olA.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olAB = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)

Application.Volatile
sNameWanted = rRng.Value
sRetValue = "Not Found"

On Error Resume Next

For lItem = 1 To olAB.Items.Count
    With olAB.Items(lItem)
        If sNameWanted = .FullName Then
            Select Case iWanted
                Case 1
                    sRetValue = .CompanyName
                Case 2
                    sRetValue = .BusinessAddress
                Case 3
                    sRetValue = .BusinessAddressCity
                Case 4
                    sRetValue = .BusinessAddressState
                Case 5
                    sRetValue = .BusinessAddressPostalCode
                Case 6
                    sRetValue = .BusinessTelephoneNumber
                Case 7
                    sRetValue = .Email1Address
            End Select
        End If
    End With
Next lItem
olA.Quit
GrabContactInfo = sRetValue
End Function
```

Any information is helpful

Answer (score 5):

Instead of looping through ***all*** the items in the Contacts folder, you can use `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve` to resolve a name to an instance of the Recipient object. You can then use `AddressEntry.GetContact` to resolve it to an instance of the `ContactItem` object or `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser` to get an instance of the `ExchangeUser` object:

```
Set olA = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olA.GetNamespace("MAPI")
set olRecip = olNS.CreateRecipient("Dmitry Streblechenko")
olRecip.Resolve
set olAddrEntry = olRecip.AddressEntry
set olCont = olAddrEntry.GetContact
if not (olCont Is Nothing) Then
  'this is a contact
  'olCont is ContactItem object
  MsgBox olCont.FullName
Else
  set olExchUser = olAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser
  if not (olExchUser Is Nothing) Then
    'olExchUser is ExchangeUser object
    MsgBox olExchUser.StreetAddress
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank You for the code however once I integrated the code it did not compile.  Would you be able to give me some working code? maybe it is user error

Comment: I get a run time error 287. It is an application or object defined error.  When I click debug it highlights `olRecip.Resolve` line in the code.

Comment: Is olRecip object null?

Comment: I don't know what that means

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and when it hits, look at the value of the olRecip variable.

Comment: i did that and the value of `olRecip` is blank or `<>`.  the value of `.Resolve` is `<Expression not defined in context>`

Comment: it will not fit in this comment box should I open another question forum or is there private messaging through this site?

Comment: Show just the relevant snippets of your code similar to what you had in your original question.

Comment: `Name = Range("D2").Value
    Set olA = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olA.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olRecip = olNS.CreateRecipient(Name)
    olRecip.Resolve
    Set olAddrEntry = olRecip.AddressEntry
    Set olCont = olAddrEntry.GetContact
    If Not (olCont Is Nothing) Then
        'this is a contact
        'olCont is ContactItem object
        MsgBox olCont.FullName
    Else
    Set olExchUser = olAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser
        If Not (olExchUser Is Nothing) Then
        'olExchUser is ExchangeUser object
        MsgBox olExchUser.CompanyName
        End If
   End If
End Sub`

Comment: this code replaces everything after `Dim sRetValue As String`

Comment: What I the value of the Name variable? Does it matte what the value is?

Comment: the value is a name that I am looking up.  ex "Leeson Shockey" would be typed into the box that the `Name` variable is looking at

Comment: Can that name be resolved in Outlook if you type it in the To edit box?

Comment: Yes it does but it has to be in the format **Shockey, Leeson**

Comment: Ok, so does it work if you provide the name in that format?

Comment: So if you type "Shockey, Leeson" to the To edit box in Outlook, it gets resolved, but if you pass it to CrearteRecipient, Recipient.Resolve fails? Are you sure you are using the same profile in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

A small function that can be used in excel to retrieve the email address - can be slow on automatic calculation.

> =lookupEmail(A2)

```
Function lookupEmail(name)
    lookupEmail = ""
    Dim objApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.recipient
    
    Set myNamespace = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient(name)
    
    myRecipient.Resolve
    If myRecipient.Resolved Then
        lookupEmail = GetSMTPAdress(myRecipient)
 
    End If
End Function

Function GetSMTPAdress(recipient As Outlook.recipient)
    Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = _
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
     Set pa = recipient.PropertyAccessor
     GetSMTPAdress = pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
End Function
```